# mySQL - foreign key to multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, polymorphic-associations

I am fumbling my way through phpMyAdmin and mySQL.  I’m creating something where a customer can register multiple products.  The data coming in is:

Category > Type > Size > Color

So for example:

Cookware > Oven > 5 qt > Blue
Bakeware > Casserole > 3qt > Blue
Accessories > Textiles > N/A > Blue
Etc.

I have set up one table with categories, and 4 tables to cover each product type.

**Categories**
ID Category
1 Cookware
2 Bakeware
3 Accessories
4 Serveware

**Cookware Table**
ID Type
1  Oven
2 Skillet
3 Roaster

**Bakeware Table**
ID Type
1 Casserole
2 Pie Dish
3 Baker

Etc.

Then, in the registration table, I set up a foreign key to link the category to the category table.  So it would look something like this:

```
ID   CustID  Category  Type Size Color
1    20      2         1    11   34
1    20      1         1    9    34
```

(sorry the formatting is so terrible! not sure how to fix)
But, I’m stuck on how to link the product type to the correct product type table since it is dependent on which category they picked.  Hopefully this makes sense. Maybe I don't even need to link them and can still request the data somehow through a query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merge the last 2 tables ?

```
    ID Type        Category
    1  Oven        1
    2  Skillet     1
    3  Roaster     1
    4  Casserole   2
    5  Pie Dish    2
    6  Baker       2
```

Comment: I thought about that but it would require reprogramming the form and making that piece more complex.  Perhaps that will be easier than dealing with it on the database side though.

Comment: You can reference just one table.
Dirty solution: dont use foreign keys and handle within the application... 

Off-Topic: Use Code-Tag for formatting :)

Comment: Thanks for the code-tag formatting tip! Sorry, what do you mean by reference just one table? Are you still suggesting I merge all the types together, or in the query to get the data, I can reference the appropriate type table based on what category was selected?

Comment: I decided to merge the tables to keep things easy.